# Changing the font-family in Gmail

Tags: javascript, html, css, email, gmail

Are there any good ways to change the font family in Gmail or do I need to include some Javascipt to do so?

I am currently send an html email from my email server via a web request to a Gmail account. The page looks fine in the browser with the correct font-family. But when I open it in Gmail, the font is Arial and not what's below.

I'm using this but it's not working:

```
<tbody style="font-family: MyriadPro-Regular,cafetaRegular,georgia,serif !important; font-size: 22px;">
```

Comment: i have reclarified my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use javascript in a gmail email. If using the fonts provided by the editor itself is not enough, you can compose HTML emails in gmail ([although you need to install something first](http://www.labnol.org/internet/send-html-email/19672/)). Alternatively you can use a browser based  web app such as [this one](http://ctrlq.org/html-mail/).

Once you have done this, you can use css styling, but this must be done through inline styles i.e.

```
<div style="font-family: times, serif;">
```

as you cannot link to external stylesheets.

**Edit**: Email will ignore the `tbody` tag so try using a `div` or `p` instead

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear, but i edited above, thx

Comment: yeah you have to do it at the <td> or <span> elements in Gmail or it gets overridden or not seen in <tbody>, <tr>, etc...